# jQuery templates - events when render

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

It's possible to call event e.g. success in jQuery templates. I know, I can use live for bind events, but I need this to jQuery qTip2 tooltips.
Now I get JSON and in success event ajax function use tmpl function:

```
$('#tmpl-threads-list').tmpl(d.threads).appendTo('#topics section.forums-list');
```

and next I call function with init tooltips. But this is function is done before templates are render. I require any solution to call function when template is rendered.

Comment: Could you show the surrounding code? The code snippet you've posted shouldn't be asynchronous...

Answer (score 1):

Solution is here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/events/#live